# pthread updates a common variable

Tags: android

In my problem, I create a pthread using pthread_create(), say myThread.

They both share a common variable "done" for the main thread to tell the myThread stops reading from the socket.

in my pthread, I have a loop:

```
// done is a common variable
while (!done && socket->read(&buffer) == OK) {
    // do something....
}
```

Some times, I want to tell myThread to stop reading from socket, so I do:

```
done = true;
  void *test;
    pthread_join(myThread, &test);
```

Will this cause a race condition? i.e. will myThread not see my main thread update the value of 'done' before it blocks on the read call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a variable in one thread and reading it in another needs synchronization (such as a mutex) to avoid race conditions.

If this is a real socket and not a strange object, consider calling `shutdown()` to tear down the connection and wake up blocked threads while keeping the file descriptor valid, see [Wake up thread blocked on accept() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486335/wake-up-thread-blocked-on-accept-call/2489066#2489066). Once the read has failed, myThread locks the mutex and checks the done variable.

Other methods include calling `poll()` on the socket and a pipe for delivering the shutdown message.