# How to change socket's listening port after accept() was called?

Tags: sockets, freertos, lwip

I'd like to change the port a socket is listening on. The problem is that I can't do it as long as a call to accept() is still in progress. I tried closing the socket expecting accept() to exit and return negative value. But it doesn't happen on FreeRTOS. When I close the socket from different thread accept() still executes. The only workaround I came up with is to set a flag in a variable, make a TCP connection and then when accept() finishes, check the flag, bind() with new port nad call listen(). But maybe there is a more elegant method?

Comment: What EJP said below is correct. If you are needing to close the socket from a different thread - see this question and answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486335/wake-up-thread-blocked-on-accept-call

Comment: Using `select()` to know when to call `accept()` is the right way to go in this situation. Don't `accept()` a new client until `select()` says to. Then "wake up" `select()` when you need to close the old listening before opening a new listening socket.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to change the port a socket is listening on.

You can't.  You have to close the current listening socket and then open a new listening socket.

> The problem is that I can't do it as long as a call to accept() is still in progress.

You have to unblock `accept()` first, then you can close the listening socket.

> I tried closing the socket

That's the right way to implement the requirement, but it doesn't constitute changing the port that the socket is listening on. You have to create a new socket listening on the new port.

I would create the new socket and get it into operation and set a flag saying not to accept any further connections on the old socket: when `accept()` on the old socket finally unblocks, check the flag, and if it's set then close the accepted connection and the old listening socket and exit that accept loop and thread.

It's a strange requirement. What's the purpose?

Comment: The requirement is to have configurable listening port. The port is for binary protocol, configuration is through web interface. My first sentence could have been misleading. I just need to stop listening on one port and start listening on a new one. It doesn't have to be the same socket. Your solution is an interesting idea but requires creating the new socket somewhere outside the server task/thread. Doing it in web server task or a new task for binary protocol leads to a messy code. That's why I need to unblock accept() on demand so the task can deal with creating new socket by itself.

Comment: It doesn't 'require creating a new socket somewhere outside the server task/thread'.