# How to break from the blocking TcpListener::accept call?

Tags: multithreading, api, rust, shutdown

I'm running the [`accept` function of a TCP listener](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-beta/std/net/struct.TcpListener.html#method.accept) in a loop in a separate thread. I would like to shutdown this thread gracefully, but I can't see any kind of `shutdown` mechanism which I could use to break from accepting.

My current approach looks something like this:

```
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::thread::spawn;

fn main() {
    let tcp_listener = TcpListener::bind((("0.0.0.0"), 0)).unwrap();
    let tcp_listener2 = tcp_listener.try_clone().unwrap();

    let t = spawn(move || {
        loop {
            match tcp_listener2.accept() {
                Ok(_) => { }
                Err(_) => { break; }
           }
        }
    });

    drop(tcp_listener);
    assert!(t.join().is_ok());
}
```

But that doesn't do the trick (probably because I drop only the cloned copy?). Any thought on how to properly shutdown such thread?

(for reference, [I asked this question on rust user forum as well](http://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-break-from-the-blocking-tcplistener-accept-call/894/1))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is a fundamental one, as in the end the `accept()` call translates down to a `libc::accept()` (see [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/89436536246250ee3cbc47a61c31037ce7558c06/src/libstd/sys/unix/net.rs#L54) and [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/89436536246250ee3cbc47a61c31037ce7558c06/src/libstd/sys/windows/net.rs#L89)).

The solution would be to use nonblocking-io, look at [mio](http://carllerche.github.io/mio/mio/) for example.

---

**Edi:** After some consideration I researched the possibility to interrupt the `accept()` using `close()`. It seems to be unreliable. But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489066/4316209) turned up: Using `shutdown()`. `TcpStream` exposes this function, but it seems to be the only case. Might be a shortcoming of the API?

Comment: Thanks, you're probably right that the functionality is missing in the API. I gave you +1, but I would like to wait a bit longer, maybe someone has a different explanation.