# Best way to listen for connections in C - Socket

Tags: c, sockets

I have a server running fine. This servers is a multi-client and it's working fine, but I don't think I'm using the best approach for this and the main point for this assumption is the way I 'exit' application. I'm handling signals and just exiting, but it's not right, I can't even debug using valgrind.
In my other apps, I use a global variable to hold app state, for example, `pexit` and in every thread that runs 'forever', the condition is:

```
while (!pexit) ....
```

And in the signal handle I just set 'pexit' to 'true' and everything works fine. But my problem is in listening function, which is 'blocking', therefore I can't use my global variable. Is a better way to do this without blocking?

```
while ((client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &client, (socklen_t*) & c))) {
....
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486335/wake-up-thread-blocked-on-accept-call

Comment: accept blocks until a connection is ready. please check out `man getaddrinfo` for an example of a socket server and client

Comment: The answer probably depends on the OS, which do you use? Generally I wouldn't worry too much about cleaning up at shutdown because the OS cleans up everything anyway.

Comment: @alain, it's a Linux machine. I'm not sure If I understood, but the problem is not how or when shutdown sockets, but how to keep accepting (for multiple-clients) without blocking, therefore using my 'pabort' to stop waiting and shutdown my app.

Comment: You could set the listen socket to non-blocking. BTW your `((client_sock = accept(socket ...` is not correct. accept() will return -1 on error, not zero.

Comment: You could use `select()` with a timeout to wait until a connection is ready to be accepted, and check at each wakeup whether to exit.  You can then control the window within which you can expect an exit instruction to be recognized by means of the lengtjh of the `select()` timeout.

Comment: Alternatively, you could interrupt the `accept()` call by sending a signal to the process (which could also be the means by which you cause your exit flag to be set).  Provided that signal is neither blocked nor ignored, and that you have not configured automatic restart of system calls upon its receipt,  the `accept()` call should then return -1 and set `errno` to `EINTR` (a case for which you might want special handling anyway).

Comment: On linux I would use non-blocking sockets with `epoll`. Under heavier loads, an evened design will work far better than a thread-per-client design. You can look up the code in the [facil.io library](http://facil.io) for an evented server example.

Answer (score 1):

In your main loop, instead of calling `accept()` directly, use `select()` to check for an incoming connection. Add `socket_desc` (the "mother" socket) to the list of file descriptors to be watched for *reading*, and set a suitable timeout. When `select()` returns with the bit for `socket_desc` set, you can call `accept()` without blocking. And the timeout makes sure that the `select()` call doesn't block indefinitely.